# Erro on Azure Data Factory deploy

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory, cicd

I'm trying to make a CI/CD pipeline for Data Factory folowing this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery-improvements#continuous-deployment-improvements, but when it execute the Validate task I have the folowing error:

```
    =====ERROR=====
Error: Command failed: node  /home/vsts/work/1/s/downloads/main.js validate /home/vsts/work/1/s /subscriptions/<AZsubscription>/resourceGroups/<resourceGroup>/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/<dataFactory>
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: end of file unexpected

Execution finished....
/home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/@microsoft/azure-data-factory-utilities/lib/bundle.manager.js:53
                    throw "Execution failed with exit code: " + exitCode;
                    ^
Execution failed with exit code: 2
(Use `node --trace-uncaught ...` to show where the exception was thrown)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ build: `node node_modules/@microsoft/azure-data-factory-utilities/lib/index "validate" "/home/vsts/work/1/s" "/subscriptions/<AZsubscription>/resourceGroups/<resourceGroup>/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/<dataFactory>"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vsts/.npm/_logs/2023-07-26T03_36_59_467Z-debug.log
Found npm debug log, make sure the path matches with the one in npm's output: /home/vsts/.npm/_logs/2023-07-26T03_36_59_467Z-debug.log
```